# Firebase Key's Child's data is overwritten to one on app restart or activity reopen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This piece of code runs correct. It increments the value by 1 but when i restart the app or relaunch the activity the data is overwritten to one.

```
int regEvents = 0;
String events_registered = "0";

private void btnAddRegisteredEvents() {
    final String key2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final DatabaseReference databaseReferenceObj2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("Users")
            .child(key2).child("eventsregistered");
    databaseReferenceObj2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            events_registered = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    regEvents = Integer.parseInt(events_registered) + 1;
    databaseReferenceObj2.setValue(String.valueOf(regEvents));


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because each time you start your app, you are initializing `events_registered` with a value of `"0"` and then immediately setting the value in your database to `events_registered+1`. The code contained within the event listener you defined is not executing before this set operation as it is asynchronous.

To increment a value stored in the database, it is best to use a [transaction operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) containing a [transaction handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler). This is a bundled read-modify-update operation useful for any operation that relies on the current database value such as incremental counters.

```java
private void btnAddRegisteredEvents() {

    final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final DatabaseReference eventsRegisteredRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference().child("Users")
        .child(userId).child("eventsregistered");

    eventsRegisteredRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            int eventsregistered = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class); // parses string as integer
            eventsregistered++;
            mutableData.setValue(eventsregistered);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData); // return updated data to be written
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: return Transaction.success(eventsregistered); // return new value to be written

This code is not working.

Comment: Ah right, you've got to return `mutableData` not the raw value. Code has been updated. You could also flatten a few of those lines into `mutableData.setValue(mutableData.getValue(Integer.class) + 1);` but it's not so readable.

Comment: Sorry to say, the value is still not being updated in the firebase database.

Comment: Basically i am trying to update the number of payments made for an event by a user and on completion of the payment, the user's number of event registered counter increases. But your code is not incrementing the number rather it returns a null counter.

Here is the link to the JSON structure of my database
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cRWuk2Gqqk5ljSX6hdv5ivbuR43Sj1Jy

Here is a snapshot of the tree,
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11p5xmLjHC49sqzvXYo3Au5GdNnULdnom

Comment: Unfortunately I mainly use the web and node sdks, with limited knowledge of how the Java SDK works. The theory of this code is correct, but it seems there is some syntax error causing an issue. The next debug step would be to use `getValue(String.class)`, parse the integer, increment it, convert it back to a string and pass it to `setValue()`. Try working with what's above and the [code example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) and see what you can piece together.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you start the activity you are re-intializing events_registered variable value to 0 and it get's updated to that value. So here you just save that last incremented value in a shared preference or database. Next time when you launch the application. Just read the shared preference value and add shared preference value+1 to your value. That's all problem is solved. Now you will get the value updated correctly.